# Não consigo colocar as minhas opções todas funcionando

Tags: python

Só funciona a opção 1 de calculadora, as outras nem sequer printam nada quando são chamadas! Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import datetime
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datemain import currentlydate
from sistemabanco import Acc
from sistemabanco import ContaBlock
import math



print('@' * 50)
print('          ', 'Welcome to NeryPhone', '          ')
while (True):
    print('       ', 'Escolha as suas opcoes abaixo!', '          ')
    print('[Calculadora(1)] -> Voce podera fazer calculos')
    print('[Conta Bancaria(2)] -> Voce podera operar sua conta bancaria!')
    print('[Sair(3)] -> Celular sera desligado!')
    print('[Agenda Telefonica(4)] -> Sera mostrado sua agenda telefonica!')
    print()
    oopt = input('O que voce deseja fazer? [1-4]')

    while True:
        try:
         if oopt == '1':
             print('Calculadora')
             print('Estes sao os operadores possiveis: +, -, /, *, ** ou Raiz ')
             operator = input('Qual operação você deseja fazer? ').title()
             n1 = float(input('1º Valor: '))
             n2 = float(input('2º Valor: '))
             if operator == '+':
                 result = n1 + n2
                 print('Valor 1 + Valor2 -->' , result)

             elif operator == '-':
                 result = n1 - n2
                 print('Valor 1 - Valor2 -->' , result)

             elif operator == '/' or '\'':
                 result = n1 / n2
                 assert n1 and n2 > 0, 'Você digitou 0 ou um valor irreal!'
                 print('Valor 1 / Valor 2 -->' , result)
             
             elif operator == '*':
                 result = n1 * n2
                 print('Valor 1 * Valor2 -->' , result)
             
             elif operator == '**':
                 result = n1 ** n2
                 print('Valor 1² -->', result)
            
             elif operator == 'Raiz':
                 result = math.sqrt(n1)
                 print('A raiz do valor é:' , result)
             else:
                 print('Valor não reconhecido, tente novamente!')
             close = input('Você deseja encerrar o programa? (S/N)').title()
             if close == 'S':
                 break
             else:
                 pass    
        
        except ValueError:
            print('Digite valores reais')
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Não divida por 0!')

     
    while True:
        if oopt == '4':
            comando = "Continue"
            contatos = {}
            while comando != 'sair':
                comando = input('Registro, Pesquisar, Exibir').title()
                if comando == 'Registrar':
                    try:
                        nome = input('Nome: ').strip()
                        telefone = int(input('Telefone: ')).strip()
                        contatos[nome] = {
                        "Nome": nome,
                        "Telefone": telefone
                      }
                    except ValueError:
                        print('Insira números no telefone!')
                
                elif comando == 'Pesquisar':
                    nome = input('Nome: ')
                    if nome in contatos:
                        contato = contatos[nome]
                        print(contato)
                    else:
                        print('Contato nao encontrado!')
                
                elif comando == 'Exibir':
                    print(contatos)
                else:
                    print('Valor nao encontrado!')
                
                close2 = input('Voce deseja sair do programa? (S/N)').title()
                if close2 == 'S':
                    break
                else:
                    pass
        
        if oopt == '3':
            break
    
    while True:
        if oopt == '2':
            namebanc = input('Your name: ')
            x = 0
            
            print(f'Olá {namebanc} \n Data: {currentlydate(x)}')
            print('@@@@@@Sacar@@@@@@')
            print('@@@@@@Depositar@@@@@@')
            print('@@@@@@Sair@@@@@@')
            optbank = input('Qual opção você deseja? ').title()

            while optbank != 'Sair':
                if optbank == 'Sacar':
                    try:
                        saldo = int(input('Seu saldo: '))
                        while True:
                            saque = int(input('Quanto você deseja sacar? '))
                            assert saldo - saque >= 0, 'Saldo insuficiente para Saque'
                            operation = saldo - saque
                            print(f'Seu saldo atual: {operation}')
                            closebank1 = input('Você deseja sair? (S/N)').title()
                            if closebank1 == 'S':
                                break
                            else:
                                pass
                    except ValueError:
                        print('Valor inválido!')
                
                
                elif optbank == 'Depositar':
                    try:
                        print(f'Seu saldo atual: {operation}')
                        while True:
                            deposit = int(input('Quanto você deseja depositar?'))
                            assert deposit > 0, 'Valor irreal para depósito'
                            depop = operation + deposit
                            print(f'Seu saldo atual: {depop}')
                            closebank2 = input('Você deseja sair? (S/N)').title()
                            if closebank2 == 'S':
                                break
                            else:
                                pass
                    except ValueError:
                        print('Valor irreal!')

                elif optbank == 'Sair':
                    break
```

Answer (score -1):

Vamos olhar a sua sequência de execução:

```
oopt = input('O que voce deseja fazer? [1-4]')

while True:
    try:
        if oopt == '1':
             # ...

    except ValueError:
        print('Digite valores reais')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Não divida por 0!')
```

Caso `oopt` seja `'2'`, o programa

1. entra no loop infinito;
2. entra no bloco de tratamento de exceção;
3. verifica se `oopt` é igual a `'1'`;
4. como a condição é falsa, o programa sai do bloco `try`;
5. como nenhuma exceção ocorreu, o programa sai do bloco de tratamento de exceção;
6. como o loop infinito não foi quebrado em nenhum momento, o programa volta para o passo 1.

Por isso nada acontece caso você insira `oopt` diferente de `'1'`. Caso você realmente queira usar um loop infinito junto com um bloco de tratamento de exceção, basta inverter a ordem dos `if`s, refatorando seu código para

```
oopt = input('O que voce deseja fazer? [1-4]')

if oopt == '1':
    while True:
        try:
            # ...

        except ValueError:
            print('Digite valores reais')
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Não divida por 0!')

elif oopt == '4':
    while True:
        # ...

elif oopt == '3':
    pass

elif oopt == '2':
    while True:
        #...
```